# Is it possible to automate Google Spreadsheets Scripts (e.g. without an event to trigger them)?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Does anyone know if it's possible to use Google Apps Scripts to run without needed a manual event? Meaning - I would like to set up a spreadsheet to send a form every day at a specified time. I have figured out how to manually send the form by executing a script, but has Google implemented to ability to set a script to run in the future (and on a recurring basis)?

I have searched for an answer but can't find one.

Thanks...

Answer (score 51):

Now it is possible to add time based events.

from: http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_events.html

- Edit -> Current project's triggers. You see a panel with the message No triggers set up. Click here to add one now.
- Click the link.
- Under Run, select the function you want executed on schedule.
- Under Events, select Time-driven.
- On the first drop-down list that appears, select Week timer, Day timer, Hour timer, or Minutes timer. Depending on which you select, you see one or two additional lists. To test the trigger and your function, you might want to pick a short duration so that you can see the execution without having to wait hours or days.
- If you picked Week timer, select a day of the week and time of day.
- If you picked Day timer, select an hour.
- If you picked Hour timer, select an interval of hours.
- If you picked Minutes timer, select an interval of minutes.
- Click Save.
- To ensure that the script runs at the correct time for a particular time zone, click File > Properties, select a time zone, and click Save.

Comment: I found it under the following menu: `Resources -> Current project's triggers`

Comment: Actually found it under Edit => current project's triggers - they must have moved it around through the years

Comment: There was no edit menu when I looked at this but there was a "trigger" entry in the sidebar which allowed time based events.

Answer (score 10):

It's actually possible. Have a look at http://code.google.com/googleapps/appsscript/guide_events.html#Installable

Answer (score 2):

You can do that using the `newTrigger` function of the `ScriptApp` class.

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('getEmails')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();
}
```

You can see the entire documentation at:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String)

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/trigger-builder

Comment: Do you really think this is helpful like that ? not very well introduced nor explained, at the least. By the way , you mention "every 6 hours" and you set value to 1... please re-read.

Comment: i copied just my code i wanted  every 1 hour i thouth it will be usefull.'function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
  // Trigger every 6 hours.
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('your function')
      .timeBased()
      .everyHours(6)
      .create();
}'