# Automation of excel data load in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

How to upload  an excel which  will be available every morning at 7 am in  google cloud storage . At certain time in a day, a script should run and load that data in the excel into a table in Bigquery.Could anyone help me out in writing the script.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possible options to do that:

1. You can create an app that will grab that file on specified time, auth in google infrastructure and create a request to load data.
   Link to documentation: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/authorization
2. You can register on website https://platform.cooperation534.com create a new process using connector CSV and BigQuery, write a simple mapper in Python language and set run date to 7am and scheduler to 24 hour's. If you will have some problems write to me and I will help you with setting this properly.
   If you doesn't know the Python write to me and I will write for you that mapping code :)

Comment: sorry iam new to python language.can you pls help me how to write the mapping code in python

Comment: Please give me a link to file which you would like to send to BigQuery and i will write a mapping code for you and schema for BigQuery :)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Google Apps Script to run a cron operation
[Is it possible to automate Google Spreadsheets Scripts (e.g. without an event to trigger them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018875/is-it-possible-to-automate-google-spreadsheets-scripts-e-g-without-an-event-to)
and
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/bigquery