# Google Spreadsheet dynamic conditional formatting with merged dropdown

Tags: google-sheets, gs-conditional-formatting

**How my sheet works**

I'm making a spreadsheet to show how much parts I have. By using a dropdown, am I able to show that I created a product. With conditional formatting I am showing that having 0 items isn't an issue when the product is created. Created products with 0 items change from red to purple. Purple means it doesn't matter to have 0 items from this product.

**My issue**

My issue starts with my dropdown. If I merge cells, The value will go into the upperleft cell. This means other cells inside the merged cell are blank. This gives me a problem with conditional formatting.

**My conditional formatting code example:**

```
=if($D2=0;$E2="Created")
```

I have to change this code for every cell because of the condition combined with a dropdown. Having more than 250 rows would be inhumanly hard to do by hand.

**My questions**

1. Are there ways to give all cells of a merged cell the value of the combined cell in an efficient way?
2. Is there a better way to make my conditional formatting code applyable to merged cells?

**This is my sheet**

[Product items collected sheet link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ZGH1gRXFzoAsayexdbslKmatQPIDZDYlRWZjupOaJw/edit?usp=sharing) (Shows the problem and solution!)

[Product items collected sheet image (Version 1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Il8rm.png)

[Product items collected sheet image (Version 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAQDC.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the heart of this question is the operation of merged cells. When a cell is merged, say over several rows, only the cell at the top left of the merged cell can contain data, respond to conditional formatting, and so on. In a manner of speaking the other cells cease to exist and values CANNOT be assign to them.

The questioner asks:
Q: Are there ways to give all cells of a merged cell the value of the combined cell in an efficient way?
A: No. Not just in an "efficient" way; it's just not possible.

Q: Is there a better way to make my conditional formatting code applicable to merged cells?
A: No and yes ;)
No. In so far as a merged cell is concerned, everything is driven by the value in the top cell of the merged range. There are no other options for the "rest" of the merged cell.
Yes. I'd create a "helper" cells in Column F as in this screenshot

---

[image: Helper Column before and after]

---

The code to achieve this is dynamic - it will automatically adapt to adding more products, more items, etc.

The logic is fairly simple: Start in F2, test whether E2 has a value (that is, is it the top of the merged cell?). If yes, then assign the value of E2 to F2 AND put that value in a variable for the following cells. If no, the cell in Column E must be part of a merged cell, so assign the value for Column F to the variable that was saved earlier.

---

```
function so5270705902() {

    // basic declarations
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // note this is going to work on the second sheet in the spreadsheet - this can be edited.
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

    // Column B contains no merged cells, and always contains data (it is the BOM for the Products).
    // so we'll use it to established the last row of data.
    var Bvals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
    var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length;

    // Row 1 is a header row, so data commences in Row 2 - this can be edited
    var dataStart = 2;
    // Logger.log("the last row in column D = "+Blast);// DEBUG


    // set up to loop through the rows of Column F
    var mergedcellvalue = "";

    for (i = dataStart; i < (Blast + 1); i++) {

        // set the range for the row
        var range = sheet.getRange(i, 6);
        //Logger.log("row#"+i+" = "+range.getA1Notation()); DEBUG


        // get the value in column E
        var ECell = range.offset(0, -1);
        var ECellVal = ECell.getValue();
        //Logger.log("offsetrange#"+i+" range value = "+ECellVal);
        //Logger.log("Column E, row#"+i+", value = "+ECell.getA1Notation()+" range value = "+ECellVal);//DEBUG

        // when a row is merged, on the top row contains any data
        // so we'll evaluate to see whether there is any value in this row in Column E
        if (ECell.isBlank()) {

            //Logger.log("ECell is blank. We're in the middle of the Merged Cell"); ??DEBUG

            // Set the value to the lastes value of "mergedcellvalue"
            range.setValue(mergedcellvalue);

        } else {

            //Logger.log("ECell has a value. We're at the top of the merged cell");//DEBUG

            // paste the ECellVal into this range
            range.setValue(ECellVal);

            // Update the "mergedcellvalue" variable so that it can be applied against lower cells of this merged cell
            mergedcellvalue = ECellVal;

        } // end of the if isblank

    } // end of the loop through column F

}
```

---

### UPDATE 22 October 2018

For development purposes, I used a small range of only 14 rows in Column E. However the questioner's data covers over 250 rows, so I expanded development testing to cover 336 rows (yeah, I know, but I was copy/pasting and I ended up with 336 and was too lazy to delete any rows. OK?). I found that the code took over 81 seconds to process. Not good.

The primary reason (about 80 seconds worth) for the long processing time is that there is a `getValue` statement within the loop -  `var ECellVal = ECell.getValue();`. This costs about 0.2 seconds per instance. Including `getValue` in a loop is a classic performance mistake. My bad. So I modified the code to get the values of Column E **BEFORE** the loop
`var Evals = sheet.getRange("e2:E").getValues();`.

I was surprised when the execution time stayed around the same mark. The reason was that the `isBlank` evaluation -  `if (ECell.isBlank()) {` which previously took no time at all, was now consuming @0.2 second per instance. Not good++. So after searching Stack Overflow, I modified this line as follows:
`if (!Evals[(i-dataStart)][0]) {`.

Including `setValues` in a loop is also asking for trouble. An option would have been to write the values to an array and then, after the loop, update the Column E values with the array. However in this case, the execution time doesn't seem to have suffered and I'm leaving the `setValues` inside the loop.

With these two changes, total execution time is now 1.158 seconds. That's a percentage reduction of , um, **a LOT**.

---

```
function so5270705903() {

    // basic declarations
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    // note this is going to work on the second sheet in the spreadsheet - this can be edited.
    var sheet = ss.getSheets()[2];

    // Column B contains no merged cells, and always contains data (it is the BOM for the Products).
    // so we'll use it to established the last row of data.
    var Bvals = sheet.getRange("B1:B").getValues();
    var Blast = Bvals.filter(String).length;

    // Row 1 is a header row, so data commences in Row 2 - this can be edited
    var dataStart = 2;
    // Logger.log("the last row in column D = "+Blast);// DEBUG


    // set up to loop through the rows of Column F
    var mergedcellvalue = "";

    // get the values for Column E BEFORE the loop
    var Evals = sheet.getRange("e2:E").getValues();

    for (i = dataStart; i < (Blast + 1); i++) {



        // set the range for the row
        var range = sheet.getRange(i, 6);
        //Logger.log("row#"+i+" = "+range.getA1Notation()); DEBUG


        // get the value in column E
        var ECell = range.offset(0, -1);

        var ECellVal = Evals[(i - dataStart)][0];

        //Logger.log("Column E, row#"+i+", value = "+ECell.getA1Notation()+" range value = "+ECellVal);//DEBU

        // when a row is merged, on the top row contains any data
        // so we'll evaluate to see whether there is any value in this row in Column E
        // instead is isblank, which was talking 0.2 seconds to evaluate, this if is more simple
        if (!Evals[(i - dataStart)][0]) {

            //Logger.log("ECell is blank. We're in the middle of the Merged Cell"); //DEBUG

            // Set the value to the lastes value of "mergedcellvalue"
            range.setValue(mergedcellvalue);

        } else {

            //Logger.log("ECell has a value. We're at the top of the merged cell");//DEBUG

            // paste the ECellVal into this range
            range.setValue(ECellVal);

            // Update the "mergedcellvalue" variable so that it can be applied against lower cells of this merged cell
            mergedcellvalue = ECellVal;

        } // end of the if isblank

    } // end of the loop through column F

}
```

---

### UPDATE 3 March 2019

The questioner made his final changes to the code. This code is the final solution.

---

```
function reloadCreatedCells() {

  // Basic declarations.
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  // Note this is going to work on the second sheet in the spreadsheet - this can be edited.
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];

  // Column B contains no merged cells, and always contains data (it is the BOM for the Products).
  // so we'll use it to established the last row of data.
  var D_vals = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var D_last = D_vals.filter(String).length;

  // First row with data.
  var dataStart = 2;

  // Set up to loop through the rows of Column H - K.
  var mergedcellvalue = "";

  // Get the values for Column H - K BEFORE the loop.
  var H_K_vals = sheet.getRange("H2:K").getValues();

  // How many people we have.
  var people = 4;

  // The first vertical row.
  var rowStart = 12;

  // Horizontal rows.
  for (var h = 0; h < people; h++) {

    // Vertical rows.
    for (var v = dataStart; v < D_last; v++) {

      // Set the range for the row.
      var range = sheet.getRange(v, rowStart + h);
      // Logger.log(range.getA1Notation()); //DEBUG

      // Get the value in column H - K.
      var H_K_Cell = range.offset(0, -people);

      // Adding Created and not created values inside L - O.
      var H_K_CellVal = H_K_vals[(v - dataStart)][h];
      // Logger.log(H_K_Cell.getA1Notation() + ': ' + H_K_CellVal); //DEBUG

      // When a row is merged, the value is only inside the top row.
      // Therefore, you need to check if the value is empty or not.
      // If the value is empty. Place the top value of the merged cell inside the empty cell.
      if (!H_K_vals[(v - dataStart)][h]) {
        // Logger.log(H_K_Cell.getA1Notation() + ": is blank. We're below the top cell of the merged cell."); //DEBUG

        // Set the value to the top cell of the merged cell with "mergedcellvalue".
        range.setValue(mergedcellvalue);

      } else {
        // Logger.log(H_K_Cell.getA1Notation() + ": has a value. We're at the top of the merged cell."); //DEBUG

        // Paste the H_K_CellVal into this range.
        range.setValue(H_K_CellVal);

        // Update the "mergedcellvalue" variable, so that it can be applied against lower cells of this merged cell.
        mergedcellvalue = H_K_CellVal;

      } // end of the if isblank.

    } // End of the vertical row loop.
  } // End of the horizontal row loop.
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you! You solved my problem! I have also added a trigger for your code to run when the spreadsheet changes.

Comment: The only problem i'm facing is the performance. It takes a while to run this code for 250 rows. I am also doing it for 4 people, so that means it will take a while to update 4 columns. I don't know if there is a way to improve the performance? It is taking 65 seconds to get to a cell at row 258 for one column, so it takes a few minutes with 4 columns.

Comment: I hope it could be solved, because I have to choose between instant speed with hand written conditional formatting formula's or few minutes to change a color with automatic results.

Comment: Performance of Google Sheets is a subject in its own right, but I'll have a look and see which bits of the code are slowest and then whether/how they can be improved. BTW, if you liked this answer, you might approve it an the accepted answer. I've noted your performance notes above. I'll get back to you.

Comment: @ThomKok You said “I have also added a trigger for your code to run when the spreadsheet changes”. What is the trigger?

Comment: @ThomKok Refer update. If your performance is still slow, that is a new issue and a new question. Reasoning: the code builds the helper column BUT updates **EVERY** cell in the column (+/-285 conditionally-formatted cells) regardless of whether the adjacent merged cell (Column E) has changed. There's the performance hit. A new goal would be to update ONLY the helper cells adjacent to a changed Column E-merged cell. This requires identifying and tracking the merged cells. I wrote most of that code, just deleted it from the final version. So, I think a new question is required. Over to you.

Comment: @ThomKok My bad. This may be another option for you to explore. Refer Stack Overflow [How to speed up heavy conditional formatting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060471/how-to-speed-up-heavy-conditional-formatting-rules). Ingenious.

Comment: I am using the "on change" trigger on my sheet. I am also going to add your new update to my sheet. It works very fast! This will solve the performance issue. I still have a small question. Can you also modify your code to handle more columns? I have for example 4 people with created cells. Can you do this for me? I cannot make this code as efficient as you can. I have changed my spreadsheet example to help you understand what I mean. You can also see my version 2 image if you want.

Comment: @ThomKok "I am using the "on change" trigger on my sheet." That sounds like the code would be firing every few seconds. There are plenty of examples on StockOverflow and StackExchange Webapps about limiting when code fires. You might care to look at that. "Can you also modify your code to handle more columns?" No. This site exists to assist you to code or overcome specific problems, it's not a bespoke coding service. If you have managed to expand the original code to accommodate 4 users, plus add a trigger then the changes required should be well within your competence.

Comment: I have finally done it! The code works for more people. I have also added the solution in "Product items collected sheet link" to show how the code works in the sheet.

Comment: Congrats. I will add it as an update. It might as well be displayed for someone who, in the future, is trying to do the same thing. Well done for perservering. I'm betting that you've got a better handle on code now than last October.