# How to auto refresh google sheet daily once/weekly/monthly?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have created a google sheet with SQL script with plx which I will sharing it with the customer. The issue i have to refresh the report manually daily. There is no auto refresh option. Can someone suggest a way to auto refresh the data whole data in the report.

I saw videos that show refresh option I don't know for what reason its not coming for me. Please suggest an Idea.

Thanks you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to automate Google Spreadsheets Scripts (e.g. without an event to trigger them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018875/is-it-possible-to-automate-google-spreadsheets-scripts-e-g-without-an-event-to)

Comment: Welocme to SO. Please take a moment to read through the articles in https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 0):

You have a wide range of [triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#available_types_of_triggers) to automate function execution if you use [Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/overview) which you can bind to the Spreadsheet.

You can use services like [Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) to work with the sheet using scripts.

You also have [URL Fetch Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch) and [JDBC Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/jdbc) you can use to connect to external services such as your DB.

---

#### Note:

Pay attention to the [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) triggers, which seem to me what you would end up using.

Comment: Thanks can be more specific like a real implementation sample or a code snippet. Which will really be very helpful.

Comment: My answer contains the specific documentation you should read to learn how to implement the triggers yourself.  And it also includes examples. Plus your question does not include code or samples, so it's highly unlikely that any example I write will serve your specific purpose.