# Google Apps Script to add xlsx hyperlinked in gmail into Spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, automation, gmail, email-attachments

I have a very specific task and I found many similar questions but they are all slightly different.

The script is triggered every day at 10am based of the top answer of this post: [Is it possible to automate Google Spreadsheets Scripts (e.g. without an event to trigger them)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3018875/is-it-possible-to-automate-google-spreadsheets-scripts-e-g-without-an-event-to)

I receive a report every day with lines that I want to add into the existing spreadsheet, so I get the report around 8am and then the attached data is added to the spreadsheet through the script.

The situation is that the email is an automated report from Amazon Display Advertising Analytics (Amazon DSP) and the xlsx file is hyperlined, not attached.

So the script, ideally gets the email list from my gmail account, searches for a specific email and retrieves a result. Gets the hyperlinked excel file and copies the content, except for row 1 which are the headers. Adds the content to an already existing spreadsheet.

In the end, I had the help of a Fiverr professional who scripted the code, so out of respect for him I won't publish his work, so if you are interested in it or if you need it, write me a private message!

Comment: From `The situation is that the email is an automated report from Amazon Display Advertising Analytics (Amazon DSP) and the xlsx file is hyperlined, not attached.`, in this case, I thought that the XLSX data is required to be downloaded from the URL in the Gmail message. If my understanding is correct, I thought that understanding the sample email including the URL helps us think of the solution. Can you provide the sample email?

Comment: Hi Tanaike! Thanks for replying. I am adding a screencapture of one of those emails, thanks!

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the image. When I saw your provided image, it seems that it is the rendered situation from HTML data. In your situation, I think that the URL is required to be retrieved from the HTML data. So, in this case, I think that the sample HTML data is required to think of the solution. How about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I had the help of a Fiverr professional who scripted the code, so out of respect for him I won't publish his work, so if you are interested in it or if you need it, write me a private message!